# how to make the separated vertex is the active object after separation with python?

Tags: scripting

I am trying to make a simple script but I have a problem,the problem is when I separate some vertex from my mesh and go to object mode the active object is the unselected vertex,so how to make the separated vertex is the active object after separation with python?

Comment: Could you share the script you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will lead you to the solution:

```
so = bpy.context.scene.objects
so.active = o2
for obj in so:
    obj.select = (obj==o2)
```